# java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got BLOB

Tags: hibernate, oracle11g

I am using Hibernate + Oracle in my application

I am getting error in below code

Example
1. My pojo class

```
public Test{

@Type(type = "blob2map")
public Map<String, String> param;


public Map<String, String> getParam() {
    return param;
}

public void setParam(Map<String, String> param) {
    this.param= param;
}
```

1. My Dao class method

   ```
   public List<BusinessObject> searchByExample(Class<BusinessObject> entity,
       BusinessObject example) {

   return getSession().createCriteria(entity).add(
           Example.create(example)).list();
   }
   ```

where Business object is Test.class and example test

query genereated by hibernate orOracle10gDialect is

Select this_.id,this_.param from Test where this_.param=?

Full error log is

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got BLOB

at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:125)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:305)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:272)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.receive(T4C8Oall.java:623)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:181)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.execute_for_describe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:420)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.execute_maybe_describe(OracleStatement.java:896)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.execute_maybe_describe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:452)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:986)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:2888)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:2929)
at com.csam.wsc.widget.management.BlobTester.showFilteredContent(BlobTester.java:55)
at com.csam.wsc.widget.management.BlobTester.main(BlobTester.java:98)
```